# Upgraded from Spring Boot 2.4 to 2.7 compiles fine in IDE, but when I deploy I get NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I recently switched from Spring Boot 2.4.0 to 2.7.0 to take advantage of using PEM certs, and when I compiled it worked fine, but when I deployed to my server and ran the jar file, it gave me the error below. I tried to add in the JSON dependency as well with no avail.

Sorry if it is not properly formatted, I am really new to posting.
Thank you in advanced for your help!!!

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field '*****'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '******': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/configurationprocessor/json/JSONObject

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONObject

Here is my pom.xml

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.****.operations</groupId>
<artifactId>backend</artifactId>
<version>0.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>****backend</name>


<packaging>jar</packaging>
<description>****Operations Java / SQL Backend</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    <org.modelmapper.version>2.3.5</org.modelmapper.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>${org.modelmapper.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20220320</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Why do you have a separate, and more importantly **much** lower version of `spring-boot-configuration-processor`? Its latest version is 2.7.1, so in this case you should use 2.7.0 to match the rest. You can probably remove its version, because it would really surprise me if the dependency is not managed by the parent.

Comment: I just created a simple project using https://start.spring.io/ with only the Spring Configuration Processor selected. It indeed added the dependency without any version. It was also marked as `<optional>true</optional>`, something that I'd also do here unless you need it in production.

Comment: Sorry, I was using 2.7 and that is the error it gave me, not 2.0.3. I started to play around with it and trial and error and found that 2.0.3 works, but I am really not sure why it works. That is the only thing I changed. I had it at 2.7.0 and that was when it would not work.

Do I need to have all those spring dependencies listed out? I was thinking I did not need to have them all listed out...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting   spring.config.use-legacy-processing=true ?

If that works please make sure to fix your project before springboot 3.0 as this prop will be removed.  https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4

Comment: Follow-up questions should be asked in the comments under the original question.